# In WPF 3D, How to determine whether a Cube's vertex is visible

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

We know that the cube has eight vertices, and we can easily build a cube using the Media3D of WPF. But how to determine whether the vertex of the cube is visible.

Just as the following pictures show, the red vertex should be invisible, while the others should be visible.

[image: Cube1]

[image: Cube2]

Comment: Some reading on how the Media3D depth stencil works ought to be of use here.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the faces connected to the vertex has a normal facing the camera (see back face culling), the vertex is visible. This should be pretty quick to calculate.

If you need actual visibility in a complex scene, some other solution like stencil buffer as TiberiumFusion suggested should be used.